# How to Response HTTP 504: Timer Time Out JSON

Tags: c#, android, api, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'm using `https://timercheck.io/YOURTIMERNAME/60` to create timer, and when the timer end the API Manager to return both an error code and some JSON content

This is the JSON data when timer end:

```
{"errorMessage":"504: timer timed out"}
```

When the timer still countdown:

```
{"timer":"neo308CCEACbid","request_id":"e54f484e-1e64-11e6-9552-3950b2ec2d5c","status":"ok","now":1463732937,"start_time":1463732935,"start_seconds":180,"seconds_elapsed":2,"seconds_remaining":178,"message":"Timer still running"}
```

Because of the error code, i get error on Visual Studio and App force close on my Android. I only want to get the errorMessage in JSON. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin to make this project.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I'm using this to get web response

```
 private async Task<string> FetchUserAsync(string url)
        {
            // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";

            // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
            using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    return strContent;
                }
            }
        }
```

And call it like this:

```
CekTimer dataWaktu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CekTimer>(await FetchUserAsync(url));
```

Comment: please post the relevant code from your app

Comment: Is the http statuscode of the response a 504 too?

Comment: @Jason ok, you can check again

Comment: @KaiBrummund yeah, the response of the http is 504

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `HttpClient` and `GetStringAsync`, and that the HttpResponse Status code is a 504 too, like in the Json Content.

The shortcut methods like `GetStringAsync` all make a call to `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`, which of cause throws an exception on a 504 ([see source here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L177)).

You can just make a direct get Request:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, yourUri));
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of my problem, because of webservice return error code, just simply use `WebException`  and get the `StatusCode` like this :

```
    private async Task<string> FetchUserAsync(string url)
                {
                    try
                    {
                       // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                        request.ContentType = "application/json";
                        request.Method = "GET";

                        // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
                        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
                        {
                            // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
                            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                            {
                                string strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                                return strContent;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (WebException e)
                    {
                        string a = ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode.ToString();
//Toast.MakeText(this, a, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                        if (a == "GatewayTimeout")
                        {
                            return "{'errorMessage':'504: timer timed out'}";
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            internetDropDialog();
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I think it isn't the best answer, but it can help you to move on from this problem